Problem with sound via Bluetooth after connection Ubuntu 24.04 LTS in Technisat 11IR
I connect the Technisat 10IR or 11IR radio via bluetooth with Ubuntu (I tested on 20/04, 23, 24/04 LTS) and each time the module connects, everything seems to be OK, but there is no sound. The sound appears when I turn on the Bluetooth device search option (bluetoothctl ... scan on...) after a while there is no sound.
This Technisat has a PAN9026 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth module based on 88W8977. Does it require any additional drivers? Software ?
In Linux I have Pipewire, A2DP, SBC... Everything seems fine, but there is no sound.
After pairing, when I invoke hcitool lescan in the console, it works, there is sound, but there is a crackling sound from time to time, what is it about?
